# Why Regex.toString() not equal to string literals in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string-literals

```js
console.log(/\.js$/.toString() === '/\.js$/') // false
// or
console.log(/\.js$/.toString() == '/\.js$/') // false
   
// but
console.log(/\.js$/.toString()) // /\.js$/
console.log(/\.js$/.toString() === /\.js$/.toString()) // true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when converted to a string, the meaning of `\` changes. In a string, it is used to escape characters, such as `\n` and `\t`. In a regex, it means to take the next character literally, such as `.` in your case. Thus, when converted to a string `\` must be escaped, so `/\.js$/` becomes `"/\\.js$/"`. Note that if you then feed this into the `RegExp` constructor, `"\\.js$"` would be valid, whereas `"\.js$"` would have a different meaning, and be interpreted as `/.js$/`

Answer (score 1):

`\` is a special char in string literals to escape the next char. Use 2 of them.

```js
console.log(/\.js$/.toString() === '/\\.js$/') // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the string **'`/\.js$/`**'becomes **`/.js$/`** this happens because **'.'** in js is actualy the scaped character **.**

So basically you are comparing **'`/\.js$/`**' with **`/.js$/`** that are different strings.

to achieve get the same strings you need to escape the / by changing your string literal to `'/\\.js$/'`

Answer (score 1):

See the difference your self, `console.log(/\.js$/.toString());` prints `/\.js$/` while `console.log('/\.js$/');` prints `\.js$/` which is obviously different.(so you are getting false as both string are different)

```js
console.log(/\.js$/.toString());
console.log('/\.js$/');
```